# Generate .abs file from .asm file

Tags: assembly, linker, simulation, masm32, flash-memory

I have a Micropross SC2 device as simulator.From the document we found that we can load library(Motorola formatted .abs file) on flash memory of the device.
My problem is that I have never heard about .abs file(My badluck).From this http://ece.utep.edu/courses/web3376/Assembly.html

```
I got the idea "How can we generate the .abs file".(I think so)
```

I have created a small program in assembly language(.asm file) and I am using MASM32.I have also build the file and I got .obj file and .exe file but didn't get .abs file.
So, Am I missing any step to generate the abs file?

Comment: The course page you linked to is related to the Motorola/Freescale HCS12, and specifically mentions Metrowerks Code Warrior as the development environment. What kind of CPU architecture that SC2 device simulates is unclear to me. MASM32 is an x86 assembler, and will therefore not be of any use to you if you're supposed to write HCS12 assembly.

Comment: yes, you are right.That was my fault.Now I am reading about "Motorola HC12 Assembler".But till now didn't get success to generate .abs file.